# Unable to save score with SharedPreferences

Tags: android

I don't know what's wrong, but I can't save/load the score in my application. The score shows properly when playing the game, but it just didn't save. Every time when the app is reopened, the score resets to 0. The player receives points whenever they get a specific image.

Here is a part of the code:

Layout:

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/scoreLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Score : 0"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.005"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.849" />
```

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    TextView scoreLabel;
    int score = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        scoreLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreLabel);

        final ImageView battleLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.battleLogo);
        final ImageView crateImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.crateImage);
        final ImageView prizeImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.prizeImage);
        final Button openButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.openButton);
        final Button receiveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.receiveButton);

        final Resources res = getResources();

        prizeImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        receiveButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        //setting preferences
        SharedPreferences myScore = this.getSharedPreferences("MyScore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myScore.edit();
        editor.putInt("score", score);
        editor.commit();


        openButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Random prize
                int[] cards = {R.drawable.card1, R.drawable.card2, R.drawable.card3, R.drawable.card4, R.drawable.card5,
                        R.drawable.card6, R.drawable.card7, R.drawable.card8, R.drawable.card9, R.drawable.card10, R.drawable.card11,
                        R.drawable.card12, R.drawable.card13, R.drawable.card14, R.drawable.card15, R.drawable.card16,
                        R.drawable.card17, R.drawable.card18, R.drawable.card19, R.drawable.card20, R.drawable.card21,
                        R.drawable.card22, R.drawable.card23, R.drawable.card24, R.drawable.card25, R.drawable.card26,
                        R.drawable.card27, R.drawable.card28, R.drawable.card29, R.drawable.card30, R.drawable.card31,
                        R.drawable.card32, R.drawable.card33, R.drawable.card34, R.drawable.card35};
                Random r = new Random();
                int n = r.nextInt(35);

                switch (n) {
                    case 0:
                        score += 10;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        score += 20;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        score += 30;
                        break;
                }

                scoreLabel.setText("Score : " + score);

                prizeImage.setImageResource(cards[n]);

                receiveButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                prizeImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                openButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                battleLogo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                crateImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });


        receiveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                crateImage.setImageDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.crate));

                openButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                battleLogo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                crateImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                prizeImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                receiveButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //getting preferences
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("MyScore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        score = prefs.getInt("score", 0); //0 is the default value
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to have got the String score before you committed the Shared preference  the score was  still 0.Put it after you have set the score in the `openButton.setOnClickListener`

Comment: Everytime `onCreate` is called you save `score` which is `0` on initialisation .. you're logic is incorrect. You don't need to save a default value .. just save the value when required, and retrieve in `onCreate` or wherever..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your score is getting calculated in your onClick method. So put your Shared preference save part below your score calculation.

```
switch (n) {
            case 0:
                score += 10;
                break;
            case 1:
                score += 20;
                break;
            case 3:
                score += 30;
                break;
        }


SharedPreferences myScore = this.getSharedPreferences("MyScore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myScore.edit();
editor.putInt("score", score);
editor.commit();
```

And remove the above saving code from your OnCreate as your score is 0 at that time.

Comment: Great. My pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

You always put `0` into `SharedPreferenes`, hence it's always `0` (which happens to be your default value). You may confirm this by checking return value from `commit` - it's `True` if preferences were updated successfully. Changing the `score` variable in `onClick` won't change value stored in `SharedPreferences`.

What you want to do is to update `SharedPreferences` *each time* your `score` value changes (or, more practically, when `Activity` is paused or destroyed).

Comment: Now it works. Both yours and kapsyum answers are good. Thanks for clarifying!